# Android support CardView issues with shadows

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am using `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` library and facing some problems.

Here I have simply stacked 3 `CardViews` using some margin. Running it on Android L the top shadows for top 2 cards are not seen/drawn.[image: Can't see top shadows]

Here is API level 16 drawing the cards.

[image]

Is it possible the get the top shadow always drawn?

Thanks.

**EDIT: xml code**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Comment: Can you please attach the `CardView` code in xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my study, I believe that GPU drawing updates along with elevation causes this. Since the cards are on same elevation level with same background the platform blends them. Thats why older version draws some border because it doesn't support elevation.

My fix was to add 0dp elevation for bottom card, then 1dp for middle and the top card keeps it's default elevation which is 2dp. Now there is slight border visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp" />
```

Maybe `cardElevation` do it.

Comment: I don't want to increase the elevation because it affects all the shadows, as you can see that the card bottom of stack draws the top shadow properly, but cards above that doesn't.

Comment: Maybe because the color of the shadow doesn't appear on the white.